# parsing list with mixed type of data

Tags: python, list

I have an issue with a list containing mixed data types (int and str) like this one:

```
['C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC21444KYR', 'Switch 2 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2145B4CB', 2, 'C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC214561CP', 'Switch 1 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2144B01G', 1]
```

This is an example, I received (from an API) longer lists and for some device lists with another format (just discovered it now) where the 3rd field is different. Instead of having a single int (1,2 or 3 and so one) I have "Switch 1", "Switch 2" and so on.

The best would have an order like (based only on 3rd item of the tupples) (or reversed order):

3,2,1,"Switch 1 -  - FlexStackPlus Module", "Switch 2 -  - FlexStackPlus Module", "Switch 3 -  - FlexStackPlus Module"

Or for the other type of list (or reversed order):

"Switch 3","Switch 2","Switch 1","Switch 1 -  - FlexStackPlus Module", "Switch 2 -  - FlexStackPlus Module", "Switch 3 -  - FlexStackPlus Module"

I'm trying to order the list (name self.thisParts) by device (group of 3 elements in a row) but some elements are int and are probably the reason I'm stuck.

I do the following

```
swNr = 1
while swNr <= len(thisStack) :
    while self.thisParts :
        self.findSw(swNr)
        self.findSwParts(swNr)
        swNr += 1


def findSw(self, swNR):
    for i in range (0, (len(self.thisParts)//3)):
        if (self.thisParts[i+2] == str(swNR)) or (self.thisParts[i+2] == ("Switch "+str(swNR))) :
            self.orderedParts.append(self.thisParts[(i*3):(i*3+3)])
            del self.thisParts[(i*3):(i*3+3)]


def findSwParts(self, swNR):
    for i in range (0, (len(self.thisParts)//3)):
        if ("Switch "+str(swNR)) in self.thisParts[i+2] :
            self.orderedParts.append(self.thisParts[(i*3):(i*3+3)])
            del self.thisParts[(i*3):(i*3+3)]
```

But I have the following error:

```
File "/var/www/html/GenericDeviceReportTest.py", line 166, in findSwParts
if substring in self.thisParts[i+2] :
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

...something went wrong!
```

I think it's because I have string and int in the field I'm searching, so I tried to convert the list to str but it seems to not work neither:

```
self.thisParts  = list(map(str, self.thisParts))

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

...something went wrong!
```

I have the same error if I try with a while/for (read and convert all to str) but same error each time (last one I listed).

Thanks for  your help !

Comment: What’s your ordering logic? How do you compare different data types? Show sample input and output.

Comment: you show us some code (`if switch`), the error shows another code (`if substring`) and the code of the error (`not iterable`) is not even that of the code "showed" by your error (should be `not subscriptable`, it comes from a `for` loop)

Comment: When parsing data, you need to know the data format. The example you give just looks arbitrary. If it not, then you need to make a proper parsing first.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I need to order the list like this:

tupple where 3rd element is "1", then 3rd element start with "Switch 1", then is "2" and so on (have mani list with different sizes).

The input is the list in the topic, the output should be a single list:

['WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2144B01G', 1,'Switch 1 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC21444KYR', 'Switch 2 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2145B4CB', 2, 'C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC214561CP']

or list of list:

Comment: @diggusbickus yeah I created a value at some point in case of my 1st if was not working.

I just used: substring = "Switch "+str(swNR) and used that variable in my if switch. I should have mentioned that.

for the second error as mentioned I tried with a for loop or while loop but i have the same kind of error (boolean error).

Comment: @LennartRegebro the problem is caused by the different type of data I received (from an API).

'C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC21444KYR', 'Switch 2 - FlexStackPlus Module', 
'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2145B4CB', 2,

that's the 2 kind of data I can have (str or int in 3rd field). I can't change that from my source I need to handle it in my script (and it's the source of my trouble).

Comment: @hjacquemin Add the definition of the data into the question. Which field is what? All data must have a structure to be parseable.

Comment: @LennartRegebro let me know if it's better for your understanding

Comment: @hjacquemin I would just go over the data, apparently it's three fields per item, and put them into a list of dicts: `[{'id: 'C2960X-STACK      ', 'serial': 'FOC21444KYR', 'name: 'Switch 2 - FlexStackPlus Module'}, {'id': 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L','serial':  'FCW2145B4CB', 'name': '2'}` and so on. (Obviously I just made up the field names, I don't know what that data really is, only you do, as you didn't tell us).

Comment: basically it's hardware info of a switch : hardware type + serial number + switch position in a stack

or it can be : installed module type + serial number + in which switch it's installed.

yeah I can group items per three the I still can't order everithing cause I have data type mistmatch. 3rd item of a device is or a int or a string. And for some switches "the switch position is stack" is another format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're happy with alphanumerical ordering (where numbers come before letters), you can do the following (leaving of `self`):

```
thisParts = ['C2960X-STACK     ', 'FOC21444KYR', 'Switch 2 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2145B4CB', 2, 'C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC214561CP', 'Switch 1 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2144B01G', 1]

# Create groups of 3-tuples 
thisParts = list(zip(thisParts[::3], thisParts[1::3], thisParts[2::3]))

# Sort the list, temporarily turning the tuples into strings
thisParts.sort(key=str)
# But, the comments seem to suggest an ordering by the third part of the device tuple. That would mean using the following sorting instead
thisParts.sort(key=lambda device: str(device[2]))

# Now to get back to the original list, by unnesting the list of tuples
thisParts = [item for device in thisParts for item in device]
```

and `thisParts` will be sorted in-place, per subset of 3 items (device):

```
['C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC21444KYR', 'Switch 2 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC214561CP', 'Switch 1 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2144B01G', 1, 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2145B4CB', 2]
```

---

And for the one-liner:

```
thisParts = [item for device in sorted(zip(thisParts[::3], thisParts[1::3], thisParts[2::3]), key=str) for item in device]
```

Comment: At point 2 (Create groups of 3-turples) how to y dynamically do that ? I have multiple list with different size (but same format each time).

I think this can help me but I think I still have the same error, there are int and str that I need to search for.

Basically I need to read the list, get out the tupple where 3rd element is "1" then search for all elements where 3rd element start with "Switch 1", and do the same for nomber 2, 3, 4... (depends on how mani elements I have in my lists).

Comment: @hjacquemin It's unclear what you mean by dynamically. For example, is the device size (thus, 3 elements), fixed, or is that something that may change? You would need to update your question to be more precise. My answer is tailored to your current question, which I think it answers.

Comment: I mean the list size change (from 1 tupple of 3 to 5 and more tupple of 3)

Comment: What list size change? I see nothing changing from 3 to 5 back to 3.

Comment: in my example the list is:

['C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC21444KYR', 'Switch 2 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2145B4CB', 2, 'C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC214561CP', 'Switch 1 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2144B01G', 1]

but I can have:

['C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC214561CP', 'Switch 1 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2144B01G', 1]

Comment: or (this even bigger)
['C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC21444KYR', 'Switch 2 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2145B4CB', 2, 'C2960X-STACK      ', 'FOC214561CP', 'Switch 1 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2144B01G', 3, 'FOC214561CP', 'Switch 1 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'WS-C2960X-48FPS-L', 'FCW2144B01G', 3]

at the very end (if needed) the tupple sized may changed and be variable (but not at this time)

Comment: I mean by the size list change the API can return more or less elements in my list (but always tupple of 3)

Comment: If the number of elements in your list is always a multiple of three, you're fine with the above code.

Comment: The only possible issue is that your sorting criteria seem to be actually different than what I have used, but it is not clear from your question.

Comment: last small question, the order is by switch 2, switch 1, 1, 2. Is it possible to have 1, 2, Switch 1, Switch 2. I try the reverse order but it's 2, 1, switch 1, switch 2 possible to what I want ? (Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Comment: What is the logic for the ordering?

Comment: So with your script I already have an issue with ordering. If there is 2 tupples of 3 it's ok.

But with 3*3 tupples (or more more, size is dynamic), I have:

2, 3, 1, 'Switch 1 - FlexStackPlus Module',  'Switch 2 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'Switch 3 - FlexStackPlus Module'

or in reverse:

'Switch 2 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'Switch 3 - FlexStackPlus Module', 'Switch 1 - FlexStackPlus Module',  3, 2, 1

I also found another exception where 1, 2, 3 (and so one) are 'Switch 1", "Switch 2", "Switch 3" and then the order logic is not the same

Comment: That doesn't answer my question about *your* logic for ordering.

Comment: I have also updated my question; it now produces a result you have suggested earlier.